# Material Design Lite Table - Adding Rows Dynamically Breaks Format

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, material-design-lite

This is the markup for the checkbox using material-design-lite:

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

Problem is, that the labels **for** is connected to the inputs **id**.

So when I add dynamically a new checkbox, I have to also add an id. But how do I find out which Id to add? Wouldn't it be a problem, when I am later going to add these rows into a database?

Here is the working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjNzzO

**Notice the checkbox of the new task you add**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to upgrade the element. You could call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` instead of `componentHandler.upgradeElement()`.

http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/pjbvBL

Answer (score 3):

Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register new elements using the upgradeElement function.

To upgrade all elements, use this code:

`componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`

http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic

[How Component Handler works?](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works)

Answer (score 2):

My personnal approach is to create a component. I have a working one [here](https://github.com/posva/mangare/blob/master/app/components/checkbox.vue) in coffeescript and jade

Basically you need to call `componentHandler.upgradeElements(el)`. Last time I checked this wasn't enough as it wasn't adding the ripple effect so you also need to upgrade the `lastChild`. Please note there's a difference with `componentHandler.upgradeElement(el)` and `componentHandler.upgradeElements(el)` which, if I recall correctly, walk deeply the dom.

About the problem with the `id` you should just use the `$index`. I updated the codepen so it solves your problem and I'll come back at you to help you with the style of the checkbox(which is not the question initially).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMBqj?editors=101

Comment: Your codepen no longer functions and the github link is dead.

Comment: Yeah, it was for vue 0.12 :(
I don't have new links unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `componentHandler.upgradeElement(el)` after adding the checkbox to the DOM. I'm not familiar with vue.js, so I can't suggest the specific code change required, but this [article](http://posva.net/js/2015/08/26/using-material-design-lite-with-vuejs/) seems like it has the answer.