# Material Design Lite's Checkbox design not reflecting sometime

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, material-design-lite, angularjs-ng-include

I am using Material Design lite 1.0.4, and Angular.js 1.1.3.
I have created a partial file which contains checkboxes and including that partial file using:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="'views/partials/filter.html'"></div>
```

Now the problem is, when I refresh page it displays old checkboxes sometime and sometime the material ones. The behavior is unpredictable. Sometime it work smooth on refresh.

This is one of the checkbox code:

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked />
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"> less than 4000</span>
</label>
```

The code works fine when I don't use ng-include, and write the code directly in html file. But I have to use ng-include since the partial will be included on multiple pages and that too depending on certain condition (Do not want to load template if not needed).

Comment: Maybe [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658295/material-design-lite-table-adding-rows-dynamically-breaks-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658295/material-design-lite-table-adding-rows-dynamically-breaks-format) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Materal design will not apply, since the content loaded through ajax. Need to update the design once the view loads:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    },0);
});
```

Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register new elements using the upgradeElement function.

http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic